# Issue when sending an email?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

I did a lot of research through internet but I didn't found the solution. I'm trying to send a confirmation email using `Mail::send()` in laravel 5.1, I don't want to use any third party like mailgun or mandrill because they are not free sometimes limited of usage. The problem with this is all of the confirmation of the users is in their spam folder in gmail, and trash folder in outlook. Sometimes they didn't receive the confirmation. Why is that?  Do you have any idea with this? My website is also registered to `https` so I don't think this is the problem.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mywebsite.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@mywebsite.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: I do recommend to test your e-mail sending against a service like e.g. https://www.mail-tester.com.

Comment: Hi @UweKeim I'll try this. It may be a big help .

Comment: Hi @UweKeim . I tried to use the mail-tester and I got 7.9/10 score. The one of the problems is the `MIME_HTML_ONLY`. It is saying that I have to add text version. But I've already added a text in my blade.

Answer (score 2):

Landing of an email into Spam is nothing to do with Laravel.

Either you have to change the `TXT` record of your domain.

You can check it on mail-tester which values need to be changed.
https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: Hi! I tried to use the mail-tester and I got 7.9/10 score. The one of the problems is the `MIME_HTML_ONLY`. It is saying that I have to add text version. But I've already added a text in my blade.

Comment: @Jonjie glad to know

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try testing at [Mail Tester](https://www.mail-tester.com). This can reveal a lot of information on why your emails are ending up in spam. I also recommend checking SPF and DKIM checking at [SPF &  DKIM](https://www.mail-tester.com/spf-dkim-check) checking at the same site.

Also are you hosting your emails with your hosting provider or some other third-parties like GSuite or Microsoft Exchange? These providers can influence the mail quality and spam checking greatly.

Comment: Hi! I tried to use the mail-tester and I got 7.9/10 score. The one of the problems is the `MIME_HTML_ONLY`. It is saying that I have to add text version. But I've already added a text in my blade.

Answer (score 0):

The spam classification of emails is to the discretion of the receiving mail server. There are a couple of best pratices to follow, when trying to avoid being marked as spam:

Make sure the sending server (smtp server) is allowed through

- SPF
- DKIM
- DMARC
- MX records

Further, the recipient server may check for bulk content with decentralized solutions like razor, pyzor or DCC. So, try to personalize the messages and not send bulk content. Its hard to evaluate your situation without specifics. Another problem may be the sending webserver if its in or from a country with "bad reputation" (like Russia, China). Since mail server also check [the Original-IP](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-track-the-original-location-of-an-email-via-its-ip-address/) of the email and potentially flag them as well.

**SPF**:

https://mxtoolbox.com/SPFRecordGenerator.aspx

**DKIM**:

https://dkimcore.org/tools/keys.html

**DMARC**:

https://mxtoolbox.com/DMARCRecordGenerator.aspx

To check your settings, it helps to use [mail testing solutions](https://www.mail-tester.com/) visualizing those mentioned factors as mentioned by other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Current email deliverability professional here. If you are willing to share the domain you are sending from, and the IP address initiating the sends I'm happy to check for any obvious problems.

I also heartily recommend mail-tester.com as I use it almost daily. If you want to share the link to the report I'm happy to help interpret.

The other thing to be aware of is, that IP addresses have a sender reputation that is tracked in the Email ecosystem at large. If it's a new sending IP address it has to get warmed up. Just like you cannot get a credit card with no limit as soon as you turn 21, Inbox Providers like Gmail and Hotmail are not just going to deliver everything a new sending IP starts trying to deliver to their recipients. They will essentially do some A/B testing by delivering some to the Inbox and some to the Spam/Promotions folder, and see how their recipients interact with your mailings. Gmail and thus other inbox providers are primarily concerned with how recipients interact with your mailings. Do they open, do they click links, do they add you to safe senders, etc.

-LB